# Mysql count and joins

Tags: mysql

For example I need to get a count of some particular data that is stored in `table 1` and make joins to check some connections with `table 2`, and all I need is to `count(*)`

does using `COUNT(id)` is faster than `COUNT(*)`, as far as I know MYISAM tables already have cached the count on the inner engine, but when I do operations like WHERE, JOIN, that cache doesn't work anymore right? or should I create a procedure or function in order to make it faster? will it be faster?

Comment: Count(id) is not the same as count(*) - unless you have an id for every row. count(id) will count every non null id in the result set count(*) will count every row in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Count(1) will be better choice it will be faster than count(*)

Comment: Do you have a reference that backs up this assertion?

Comment: It’s basic common rule. If you use * then dB has to check all the available columns and then count but if you use number constant then dB won’t check table structure, index etc so it will be faster

Comment: Hmm. Heres a reference which refutes that http://pretius.com/oracle-count-or-count1-that-is-the-question/ and here's another https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1-sql-server